# How to make twitter bootstrap .popover work within a .submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get twitter bootstrap's .popover working within a .submit jquery event but nothing happens after i click the submit button on my form. I'm changing the "rel" attribute of an input field so that when the user clicks the submit button, a popover is added to that field. The popover shows up if I do it the regular way of setting the rel attribute before the page is loaded.

Here's the input field:

```
<label class="control-label" for="input-name" id="input_name_label">Name *</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input rel="" data-original-title="Title" data-content="Random Text" type="text" class="span3" name="name" id="input-name">
        </div>
```

and here's the jquery function:

```
<script>
    $("#project_form").submit(function(e) {
            for(i=0;i< $("label").length;i++){
                    var str=$("label").eq(i).text();
                    if(str.charAt(str.length-1)=="*"){
                            $("label").eq(i).attr('rel','popover');
                            console.log($("label").get(i));
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('input[rel="popover"]').popover('show');
                    }
                    console.log(str.charAt(str.length-1));
            }
            $("#preferences").val($("#sortable").sortable('toArray'));
    });
    </script>
```

The function finds labels with a * as the last character and is supposed to assign a popover event to them. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was assigning a rel attribute to the label field instead of the input field. Yay basic programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

Once you make the `rel="popover"`, you need to attach the handler to it by activating:

```
$('[rel="popover"]').tooltip();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed when I tried that.

Comment: Can you post a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It has support to twitter bootstrap too!

Comment: For some reason my I can't get to the fiddle site right now on either chrome or firefox.

Comment: Hey... Did you by any chance didn't give the attribute `data-original-title`?

Comment: Well it's in the html not the javascript function. I figured out the problem has to do with assigning the rel attribute though. It's assigned but the popover isn't being initialized unless it's assigned in the html.

Comment: Oh nice. Is it solved? What is the solution?

Comment: No I still don't know what's wrong yet.

Comment: @GavinSellers If solved, please accept or give a vote up. :)